# Columns node disappeared in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I'm using SSMS (from SQL Server 2014 Developer edition) to work with SQL Azure. It's running on Windows 10. I have a number of databases set up on Azure, and have always used SSMS to work with them. I have also installed devart's dbForge Studio for SQL and use that from time to time.

I've now hit a very weird problem. I was about to create a view, and clicked the `+` next to a table to expand the nodes below. Then I clicked the `+` next to columns and got a strange error as follows:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>   For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   unknown property IsMemoryOptimized (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

Having dismissed this error, everything seemed fine, however, until I noticed that I no longer have a Columns node under that table. Or indeed any table (see screenshot).

[image: Screenshot of SSMS]

I tried the following trouble-shooting steps:

1. Restart SSMS. No change
2. Restart the PC. No change
3. Use the "Repair" option in the SQL Server Installation Center to repair the Management tools. No change

Then I tried connecting to another database entirely, and I can see columns again!  But when I connect back to this one, no columns.

To be clear, the columns ARE there, I can use them in `SELECT` statements, and I can use Script table as --> Create  and SSMS creates a script including all the column names.

I can also see the columns if I use DBForge instead of SSMS.

Anyone ever come across this? It's a real mystery to me, so I'm hoping someone here can help. Incidentally, I did follow the link in the error message above to see if there's more information, but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in SSMS. Ensure that your SSMS 2014 is updated (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46694) or, even better, use the latest version of SSMS (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2015/09/01/announcing-sql-server-management-studio-august-2015-release.aspx).

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback. I'm currently working in a client's office where the firewall's preventing me from downloading a newer version of SSMS, but I'll try tomorrow.

Thanks for the info, though. As a matter of interest - you say "It's a bug" - is that one that you know of and have seen before, or just that it sounds like it's a bug?

Comment: It's a SMO issue, possibly caused by having the incorrect version of SMO for your version of SSMS, or alternately SMO having difficulty because of a change in metadata in Azure SQL DB.  In either case, moving to the latest version of SSMS should make things better. =^)

Comment: Perfect - just installed SSMS 2016 and all good now. Thanks for your help.
Andrew

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue (no table columns node) even though I've installed the October 2015 SSMS bits. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. However, in Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer the Columns node and columns are visible and navigable.